# How can we know that implementing SAFe results in profits for the company?

Tags: cost-management, safe

Did any company measure profits after implementing [SAFe](https://www.scaledagileframework.com/)?
How can we know that total costs of implementing SAFe are less than profits?

Comment: Implementing SAFe is *always* profitable for the SAFe consultants. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find it difficult to explicitly attribute a rise in profit to an implementation of SAFe. Rather you should look at *why* SAFe is being implemented in the first place.

- Improve cross-team dependency management
- Improve forward planning
- Improve estimation accuracy for large projects

Once you know the *why* you can then design metrics that you can capture before/after, which will tell you whether SAFe had a measurable impact on your development process.